# python dataframe converting multiple datetime formats

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas.dataframe like this ('col' column has two formats):

```
    col                            val
'12/1/2013'                       value1
'1/22/2014 12:00:01 AM'           value2
'12/10/2013'                      value3
'12/31/2013'                      value4
```

I want to convert them into datetime, and I am considering using:

```
test_df['col']= test_df['col'].map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y'))    
test_df['col']= test_df['col'].map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p'))
```

Obviously either of them works for the whole df. I'm thinking about using try and except but didn't get any luck, any suggestions?

Comment: `for item in test_df.col:  test_df.col = datetime.strptime(test_df.col, '%m/%d/%Y')`

Comment: Are you referring to `pandas` dataframes?

Comment: @Christopher Pearson  oh right! You mean for each item, try and except, right? THANKS!

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Yes! `pandas`. Sorry about not mentioning it... I have updated my question, thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas.to_datetime), it's man/woman enough to handle both those formats:

```
In [4]:
df['col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'])
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 2 columns):
col    4 non-null datetime64[ns]
val    4 non-null object
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), object(1)
memory usage: 96.0+ bytes
```

The df now looks likes this:

```
In [5]:
df

Out[5]:
                  col     val
0 2013-12-01 00:00:00  value1
1 2014-01-22 00:00:01  value2
2 2013-12-10 00:00:00  value3
3 2013-12-31 00:00:00  value4
```

Comment: I guess the problem with this solution is that you provide a format to speed things up - to_datetime without a format is very slow.

Comment: @Ian true but if you don't have a fixed format then you have to do it this way

Comment: @EdChum - I think if you have a reasonable amount of data, to_datetime is too slow. I've added my answer below.

Answer (score 17):

I had two different date formats in the same column `Temps`, similar to the OP, which look like the following;

```
01.03.2017 00:00:00.000
01/03/2017 00:13
```

The timings are as follows for the two different code snippets;

```
v['Timestamp1'] = pd.to_datetime(v.Temps)
```

Took 25.5408718585968 seconds

```
v['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(v.Temps, format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M', errors='coerce')
mask = v.Timestamp.isnull()
v.loc[mask, 'Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(v[mask]['Temps'], format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f',
                                             errors='coerce')
```

Took 0.2923243045806885 seconds

In other words, if you have a small number of known formats for your datetimes, don't use to_datetime without a format!

Comment: This is a nice solution, knowing the pains of real world data you could even add a check statement where if there are still nulls after iterating over the known date formats, apply the generic to_datetime to the remaining values.


As well as the speed improvement above, this will help minimise the risk of days/months being confused and erroneous results being produced.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new column :

```
test_df['col1'] = pd.Timestamp(test_df['col']).to_datetime()
```

and then drop col and rename col1.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me.
I had two formats in my column 'fecha_hechos'. The formats where:

- 2015/03/02
- 10/02/2010

what I did was:

```
carpetas_cdmx['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(carpetas_cdmx.fecha_hechos, format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')
mask = carpetas_cdmx.Timestamp.isnull()
carpetas_cdmx.loc[mask, 'Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(carpetas_cdmx[mask]['fecha_hechos'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M',errors='coerce')
```

were: `carpetas_cdmx` is my DataFrame
and `fecha_hechos` the column with my formats